# Recursive loop on list to add to tree view

Tags: c#, recursion, tree, treeview

I have a list of a class, the class also has a class which is used to display map in the tree view.

```
public class Option
{
    public Guid Id;

    public string Title;
    public string Description;
    public List<GotoOption> GotoOptions;
    public bool IsEnd;
    public string GotoValueParent;

    public Option()
    {
        this.IsEnd = false;
        this.GotoOptions = new List<GotoOption>();
    }

}

public class GotoOption
{
    public Guid GotoId;
    public string Value;
}
```

So an Option can have many GotoOptions and these are mapped by the Guid, so if my tree view looked like:

1. Tree

1.1. Branch

1.2. Branch

1.3. Branch

There will be 4 options but the tree view will have 3 GotoOptions which link to the branches.

So my goal is to basically create a recursive loop so I don't have to manually create a loop, but I got no idea how to start it off.

Currently I have -

```
private void PopulateTreeView(Option option)
{
    if (option != null)
    {
        TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
        node.Text = option.Title;
        node.Tag = option;
        pages.Nodes.Add(node);

        foreach (GotoOption op in option.GotoOptions)
        {
            Option ops = Options.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == op.GotoId);
            TreeNode inner = new TreeNode();
            inner.Text = ops.Title;
            inner.Tag = ops;

            node.Nodes.Add(inner);

            foreach (GotoOption op2 in ops.GotoOptions)
            {
                Option opps = Options.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == op2.GotoId);
                TreeNode inner2 = new TreeNode();
                inner2.Text = opps.Title;
                inner2.Tag = opps;

                inner.Nodes.Add(inner2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which is looping for 3 layers only, but we could have 10-25 odd layers and that's a lot of manual code. I have been looking at how it works with files and folders http://www.dotnetperls.com/recursive-file-list but I can't seem to convert it from how it works there to getting it to work with my code. Any help would be great.

Comment: Options.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == op.GotoId). What is Option?

Comment: Option is the class, I have given the code for what Option is.

Comment: Sorry, I've asked about variable Options which is IEnumerable. Is it any options container?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say sorry.

Comment: Option ops = Options.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == op.GotoId); variable Options is not defined in your example. Could you show its definition?

Comment: Options is a global variable, the data for Options is fine, it just contains a list of Options.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve, I created an optional parameter passing in the created node, if the parameter is not passed in, it creates a new one.

```
private void PopulateTreeView(Option option, TreeNode existingNode = null)
{
    if (option != null)
    {
        TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode();
        newNode.Text = option.Title;
        newNode.Tag = option;

        if (existingNode == null)
        {
            pages.Nodes.Add(newNode);
        }
        else
        {
            existingNode.Nodes.Add(newNode);
        }

        foreach (GotoOption gotoOption in option.GotoOptions)
        {
            Option newOption = Options.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == gotoOption.GotoId);
            PopulateTreeView(newOption, newNode);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void CreateTreeView()
{
    var roots = Options.Select(z => z.Id)

        .Except(Options.SelectMany(z => z.GotoOptions.Select(x => x.GotoId)))

        .Select(z => Options.Single(x => x.Id == z));

    var treeNodes = roots.Select(GetNode);

    foreach (var treeNode in treeNodes)
    {
        pages.Nodes.Add(treeNode);
    }
}

private TreeNode GetNode(Option option)
{
    var node = new TreeNode
    {
        Text = option.Title,
        Tag = option
    };

    foreach (var child in option.GotoOptions.Select(z => Options.Single(x => x.Id == z.GotoId)))
    {
        node.Nodes.Add(GetNode(child));
    }

    return node;
}
```